Cluster polygons that do not overlap
I have a set of points which I buffered by 500m. I want to cluster into groups polygons that do not overlap each other, so they might be 5 different scenarios to accommodate all manholes not overlapping. Is there a tool that can create this type of scenario? eg. picture below, manholes are buffered and overlap and I want to group the ones that don't overlap



Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You've already found the tool to use, Buffer, you just used it incorrectly. Please [Edit] the Question to contain the exact parameters you have chosen, so we can tell you what you missed.

I dont understand, can you add a screenshot or drawing of what you want to do?

As alluded too by @Vince you are using the appropriate tool, you just need to read the help file! So you have accepted the default settings of the buffer tool without exploring the other parameters and created something like below.

Try changing the dissolve type to Dissolve all output features into a single feature and you get.

Output defaults to multi-part so you will have to run the data through the Multipart to single part tool.
Add a new field of type SHORT and calculate into it the OBJECTID. Then colour code it by the new ID field, an example is shown below.

Finally if you want to just keep non-overlapping then simply exclude all polygons where the area is bigger than the area of a single buffer. You could select and delete or use a query definition for that step.

I would encourage you to read the help file to understand what the optional parameters do as they can often be exactly what you need.

Thanks for getting back to me i think am explaining this really badly, i just posted an updated picture of what i mean. I want to group all manholes that dont overlap together and do that until no manholes are left.

What is your grouping criteria? You seem to have drawn some random blue lines, why group those and not altogether for example. Edit your question and don't reply here as no one should be expected to trawl through loads of comments in answers to understand your question.

noone forced you to reply you dont have to be rude, have a nice day

I'm not being rude I'm trying to guide you. You have already realised that your original question was poorly constructed. You need to go back and add the detail so others can understand your problem. It is bad practise to then continue a conversation in the comments. So you need to explain what grouping criteria you plan to use, your image is too vague. Everyone looking at this question will ask why have you grouped those altogether and not some other group, was was your ruleset? I think my answer still stands as a prefiltering stage to your analysis.
